# Xamarin.Forms Push Multiple Pages on NavigationStack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the most efficient way to push multiple pages on the stack to keep the order. I have about 25 pages which the user is nagivating through. Each page pushes the next page on the `NavigationStack`.
However, the user has to have the option to navigate directly to any page out of the 25. That means if he navigates to page n, n pages have to be pushed on the `NavigationStack` such that he can keep on navigating form there. I thought of putting all pages into an array and if the user selects page 10 for example, I will push each page from 0-9 on the `NavigationStack`. I don't know if it will work that way and if it will even be super slow. What would be the best way to handle such a scenario?

Comment: Hi , I'm interesting about this scenario . Generally , mobile application not recommands to exist too much navigation stack levels . If this scene just want to show a visual effect to show the switching of multiple pages , then not need to use navigation to achieve that . Such as a reading applications , you can go to specified page to read , that's not used navigation to achieve that . It's just a paging display. If using navigation to do that, the memory of the phone will consume too much, so the application will eventually freeze .

Comment: Thanks! I could never find that somewhere in the docs about how many pages should be on the NavigationStack because I also thought that it might consume too much memory

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(Page, Page)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.insertpagebefore?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_INavigation_InsertPageBefore_Xamarin_Forms_Page_Xamarin_Forms_Page_) and [`NavigationPage.Navigation.RemovePage(Page)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.removepage?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_INavigation_RemovePage_Xamarin_Forms_Page_)

You can use [Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) if its not too big of a change now.

Comment: Thanks but how would that improve the time complexity?

Comment: you can use Shell page with Shell navigation if its not too much of a change

Comment: I actually saw that just today but but yeah, unfortunately that would be too much change...